# Remove Comma on last value of Loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a list using a file with a for loop. Is there a way of not including a comma on the last value of my loop?

Here is the code:

```
for /F %%a in (test.txt) do (set comma=,& echo %%a !comma!) >> Output.txt
```

where test.txt contains a list:

```
ABC 
123 
EG
```

and i hope to achieve something like this:

```
ABC,
123,
EG
```

Comment: Check if the value is the last in the list (file), then remove the comma if it is.

Comment: Hi @Gerhard- are you able to provide an example? Im quite new to batch scripting. Thanks!

Comment: Will post an answer for you in a bit.

Comment: oh.. will `test.txt` ever have empty lines? (CR/LF) if so, do you want to retain or remove them?

Comment: Thanks @Gerhard nope test.txt will only contain a new line per value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a basic method. test the number of lines, only add a comma if the line number does not match the total number of lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "comma=,"
set counter=0
for /F %%i in ('type test.txt ^| find /C /V "^"') do set cnt=%%i
(for /F %%a in (test.txt) do (
    set /a counter+=1
    if !counter! lss %cnt% (
      echo %%a%comma%
    ) else (
      echo %%a
   )
))> Output.txt
```

Comment: If there is an empty line the counter will never reach the total number of lines; not an issue with the data from the question though…

Comment: @aschipfl, correct. Hence I asked op the question in a comment and after clarification I just posted this example.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable.  Then only output that line when the previous line is present. Then output the last line outside of the loop.

```
@echo off
setLocal enableDELAYedeXpansioN
set "line="
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
    if defined line echo !line!,
    set "line=%%a"
) >>Output.txt
(echo %line%)>>Output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be more of academic value, but I could not resist to give it a try using the [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) that is capable of searching beyond line-breaks, which I intend to use for retrieving all but the last line first and the last line alone later.

The tricky part was to find a way to work around the problem that the search character `.` unexpectedly matches the end-of-file as recorded in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159191). I would expect the following code to match the last line but it fails (the string `!_LF!!_CR!*!_LF!` matches lines preceding empty ones as there are two consecutive line-breaks, and the string `!_LF!.` should match lines preceding non-empty ones, excluding the last one as there is either no line-break at all or such is not followed by anything, but this fails):

```cmd
rem /* Delayed expansion is enabled, the variables `_LF` and `_CR`
rem    are set to line-feed and carriage-return characters, resp.: */
findstr /V "!_LF!!_CR!*!_LF! !_LF!." "test.txt"
```

Therefore, I had to use a way around that, unfortunately having to use multiple `findstr` commands, each of which reading the file on its own:

```cmd
rem /* Test for trailing line-break using `$`, which anchors to carriage-return;
rem    due to this, Unix-style text files are not supported by this method: */
> nul findstr /V "$" "test.txt" && (
    rem // There is no trailing line-break, so `$` does not match the last line:
    findstr "$" "test.txt"
) || (
    rem /* There is a trailing line-break, so return all lines that precede two line-breaks
    rem    with something (except line-breaks since `.` does not match such) in between: */
    findstr "!_LF!.*!_CR!!_LF!" "test.txt"
)
```

This is the full approach:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=.\test.txt" & rem // (path to target file)
(set ^"_LF=^
%= blank line =%
^") & rem // (this gathers a line-feed character)
rem // Gather a carriage-return character:
for /F %%Z in ('copy /Z "%ComSpec%" nul') do set "_CR=%%Z"

rem // Iterate through lines of text line by line:
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ('
    rem/ First test for final line-break, then do specific search: ^
        ^& ^> nul findstr /V "$" "%_FILE%" ^
        ^&^& ^(findstr "$" "%_FILE%"^) ^
        ^|^| ^(cmd /V /C findstr "!_LF!.*!_CR!!_LF!" "!_FILE!"^)
') do (
    rem /* Here all but the last lines are enumerated, which are then output
    rem    with a comma `,` appended; note that empty lines are ignored: */
    echo(%%L,
)
rem // Here the last line is returned, independent from final line-break:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
findstr /V "$" "!_FILE!" || findstr /V "!_LF!.*!_CR!!_LF!" "!_FILE!"
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks @aschipfl for the answer, its really detailed and thorough! Appreciate an alternative approach :)